# Limit of functions with 2 variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Does the limit of $\frac{x^2+y^2}{|x|+|y|}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ exists?

For me it exists because $\frac{x^2+y^2}{|x|+|y|}$ < $\frac{x^2+y^2+2|xy|}{|x|+|y|}$ = $\frac{(|x|+|y|)^2}{|x|+|y|}$  = $ |x|+|y| $ that goes to $0$.

But, according to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28x,y%29-%3E%280,0%29%20%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29/%28%7Cx%7C%2b%7Cy%7C%29), this limits does not exists.
Where I am wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Your input to WA is lacking parentheses in appropriate places. Also, it seems WA isn't interpreting the limit expression as you wish.

Comment: Sure, good clean proof, no reason for doubt. Why ask W's opinion?

Comment: Because i'm totally unsure about my results! :D

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the last step

$$ |x|+|y| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\epsilon, $$

where we used the fact

$$ |x|=\sqrt{x^2} \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$